# Better way to manage Session data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I need to persist in Session some data.
I wrote many properties like that:

```
public List<string> FillOrder
{
    get { return Session[SessionKeys.QueryFillOrder] as List<string> ?? new List<string>(); }
    set { Session[SessionKeys.QueryFillOrder] = value; }
}
```

When I have to consume this data I have to write code like that:

```
List<string> fillOrder = FillOrder;
fillOrder.Add(accordion.ID);
FillOrder = fillOrder;
```

that seems to me so ugly, because I would prefer to do that:

```
FillOrder.Add(accordion.ID);
```

but this way my value would not be saved back in Session.

Can you think of any better way to achieve the same result?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I always use a wrapper class around the ASP.NET session to simplify access to session variables:

```
public class MySession
{
    // private constructor
    private MySession()
    {
       FillOrder = new List<string>();
    }

    // Gets the current session.
    public static MySession Current
    {
      get
      {
        var session = (MySession)HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"];
        if (session == null)
        {
          session = new MySession();
          HttpContext.Current.Session["__MySession__"] = session;
        }
        return session;
      }
    }

    // **** add your session properties here, e.g like this:
    public List<string> FillOrder {get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    public int LoginId { get; set; }
}
```

This class stores one instance of itself in the ASP.NET session and allows you to access your session properties in a type-safe way from any class, e.g like this:

```
MySession.Current.FillOrder.Add(accordion.ID);

int loginId = MySession.Current.LoginId;

string property1 = MySession.Current.Property1;
MySession.Current.Property1 = newValue;

DateTime myDate = MySession.Current.MyDate;
MySession.Current.MyDate = DateTime.Now;
```

This approach has several advantages:

- you can initialize your session variables in the constructor (i.e. `new List<string>`)
- it saves you from a lot of type-casting
- you don't have to use hard-coded session keys throughout your application (e.g. Session["loginId"]
- you can document your session items by adding XML doc comments on the properties of MySession

Comment: Thank you for your answer! And, using this approach, MySession.Current.FillOrder.Add(accordionID) would be persisted automatically in Session? I can't understand the magic behind! :D

Comment: Yes! When you access MySession.Current for the first time, a new instance of MySession will be created and stored in the ASP.NET session. From then on, you will always work with that instance. Set a breakpoint the getter of the Current property to see how it works.

Comment: Yes, it's clear that I always work with that instance. What I can't understand is where it persists the changes back to Session.

Comment: I'm not sure I can explain it well in english: the ASP.NET session contains only one item: the reference to the MySession instance. Only that object is stored in the session. All other data (e.g. the FillOrder list) are properties of MySession, which you can modify as you like.

Comment: Session is not an application level variable so how can it be a static variable? If it is a static variable all the users logged into application will share the same session variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an extension method as well, but I do think the example by M4N might be better:

**EDIT** made it a generic type

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static void AddWithSession<T>(this List<T> list, T value, string key)
    {
        list.Add(value);
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = list;
    }
}

str.AddWithSession(accordion.ID,SessionKeys.QueryFillOrder);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write an own class that implements ICollection or IList, there you would implement Add as Session[...] = ...

Answer (score 0):

Using a single class for all Session variables as suggested by @M4N is a good idea, though it risks becoming a "God" class (in which case you could partition into several classes implemented in this way).

However you could just change your property implemetation as follows:

```
public List<string> FillOrder 
{     
    get 
    { 
        List<string> result = Session[SessionKeys.QueryFillOrder] as List<string>;
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = new List<string>();
            Session[SessionKeys.QueryFillOrder] = result;
        }
        return result;
    }     
    set { Session[SessionKeys.QueryFillOrder] = value; } 
}
```

In this example, you probably don't want a setter.